# treeview no show the data

Tags: search, treeview

I copied the Treeview code from the website with the students.xlsx file that executed without any error but did not show the student data

```
    import pandas 
import openpyxl
import pandas as PD
from tkinter import ttk  # for treeview
df=pd.read_excel("e:\\student.xlsx") # create data frame
print(df)
import tkinter as tk
my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry("500x350")  # width x height
my_w.title("plus2net.com")  # Adding a title
l1 = tk.Label(my_w, text="Search", width=5, font=18)  # added one Label
l1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=3, pady=10)
e1 = tk.Entry(my_w, width=35, bg="yellow", font=18)  # added one Entry box
e1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=1)
b1 = tk.Button(my_w, text="Search", width=7, font=18, command=lambda: my_search())
b1.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=2)

def my_search():
    l1 = list(df)  # List of column names as headers
    query = e1.get().strip() # get user entered string
    if query.isdigit():  # if query is number
        str1 = df["id"] == int(query)  #
    else:
        str1 = df.name.str.contains(query, case=False)  # name column value matching
    df2 = df[(str1)]  # combine all conditions using | operator
    r_set = df2.to_numpy().to list()  # Create a list of list using rows
    trv = ttk . Treeview(my_w, selectmode="browse")  # selectmode="browse" or "extended"
    trv .grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=20)  #
    trv["height"] = 10  # Number of rows to display, default is 10
    trv["show"] = "headings"
    # column identifiers
    trv["columns"] = l1
    for i in l1:
        trv .column(i, width=90, anchor="c")
        # Headings of respective columns
        trv.heading(i, text=i)
    for dt in r_set:
        v = [r for r in dt]  # creating a list from each row
        trv.insert("", "end", iid=v[0], values=v)  # adding row
my_w.mainloop()
```

please see my code and give me an idea of how the data shows in Treeview wi

Regard

Comment: If you add the [tag:python] tag to your question, it will enable syntax highlighting and make your code easier to read. (It also seems like when setting up the codeblock in your question, you added an extra indent before the first import statement.)